# ¿Como unir dos consultas cada una con funciones?

Tags: base-de-datos, postgresql

Hola a todos tengo tres tablas;

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que quiero es tener el siguiente resultado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

tengo esta consulta pero no me da el resultado, ya que se mueven las posiciones.

```
 select pp.name_template, sum(sq.qty),sum(sm.product_uom_qty) as cantidad  
from stock_quant sq JOIN stock_location sl ON sq.location_id=sl.id join 
stock_move sm on sm.product_id=sq.product_id join product_product pp on 
sq.product_id=pp.id WHERE sl.usage='internal' group by pp.name_template;
```

Si alguno de ustedes me ayudara, se los agradeceria mucho. :)

Comment: Seria mejor que agregues la estructura de tus tablas en texto y no como imagenes y a que te referies que se mieven las posiciones?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prueba haciéndolo con subconsultas y relacionándolos con idproducto, una para el total de stock y otra para la cantidad

ejemplo:

```
SELECT 
pp.name_template,
(SELECT sum(stock_location.qty) FROM stock_location where stock_location.product_id=pp.id) as stock,
(SELECT sum(stock_quant.product_uom_qty) from stock_quant where stock_quant.product_id=pp.id) as cantidad
FROM  product_product pp
```

Comment: Gracias Juan Carlos por tu respuesta, tenias razón utilice subconsultas... Saludos.